# NtQueryVirtualMemory doesn't work on 64-bits

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit

So I am working right now on a project which scans memory regions of its own process using NtQueryVirtualMemory. It works perfect on 32-bits but I keep getting STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xC0000005) in the 64-bit version. The error implies that *BaseAddress* is invalid, but I get this error for any address I use and I don't know what else to try. Even in the example I wrote below, I still get the same damn unexplainable error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef enum _MEMORY_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    MemoryBasicInformation
} MEMORY_INFORMATION_CLASS, *PMEMORY_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *PNTAPI)(
    HANDLE ProcessHandle, 
    PVOID BaseAddress, 
    MEMORY_INFORMATION_CLASS MemoryInformationClass, 
    PVOID Buffer, 
    ULONG Length, 
    PULONG ResultLength
);

void main(void)
{
    PNTAPI NtQueryVirtualMemory = (PNTAPI)GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryVirtualMemory");

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION Mbi = { 0 };
    NTSTATUS status = NtQueryVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), (PVOID)main, MemoryBasicInformation,
        &Mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION), 0);

    printf("%.8X", status);
    getchar();
}
```

I searched on google for any possible reasons but nothing turns up. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could shed some light on the matter. OS is Windows 10 64-bits and compiler is Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem. I decided to check with a debugger to see what was going on and I saw that the 2 last parameters *Length* and *ResultLength* were getting pushed as 32-bit integers onto the stack, which was obviously the reason things weren't working, but then it also made me wonder why was my program not doing the right alignment afterall? I checked again the definition of NtQueryVirtualMemory and I realized the 2 last parameters are size_t (64-bits) types and not ULONG types (32-bits). Now everything works fine!